# CRUD for array of Objects

Tags: c++, object-oriented

I'm trying a simple exercise where I want to Generate Solar Systems, and store them on an array for ease of iteration and accessability.

I've create the following classes:

```
class System {

private: 
    std::string m_Name;
    unsigned int m_ID;
    //... load system data from file.

public:
    System() {};
    System(unsigned int ID, std::string name) : m_Name(name), m_ID(ID) {

        std::cout << "Generated System" << std::endl;
    };

    ~System() {};
    
    const inline std::string GetSystemName() { return m_Name; }
};
```

Then I created the class SystemArray to group all the systems under the same galaxy.

```
class SystemArray {

private:
    std::map<unsigned int, System> m_Systems {};
    std::string m_Name;
    unsigned int m_SystemCount = 0;

public:
    SystemArray(std::string name) : m_Name(name) {

        System defaultSystem(m_SystemCount,"DEFAULT");
        m_Systems[m_SystemCount] = defaultSystem;
        m_SystemCount++;

    }
    ~SystemArray() {};

    void CreateNewSystem(std::string name) {

        System newSystem(m_SystemCount,name);
        m_Systems[m_SystemCount] = newSystem;
        m_SystemCount++;
    }

    std::string GetSystemName(unsigned int systemID) {
        if(m_Systems.count(systemID) > 0)
        {   
            return m_Systems[systemID].GetSystemName();
        };

        return "Unable to get name";
    }

    const inline std::map<unsigned int,System> GetSystemArray() { return m_Systems; }
};
```

Now I'm trying to access my systems via the Array, which is fine:

```
SystemArray newGalaxy("Milky Way");
newGalaxy.CreateNewSystem("Sol");
newGalaxy.CreateNewSystem("Tol");
newGalaxy.CreateNewSystem("Foo");

for(auto [key, value ] : newGalaxy.GetSystemArray())
{
    std::cout << key << ": " << value.GetSystemName() << std::endl;
}
```

Now I'm developing the API to be able to edit the values of the systems inside the SystemArray. And here starts my problem. I'm acessing the Systems via the SystemArray so I need to create the functions inside the System and then replicate them on the System Array, copying the values around.

I'm stuck here, since my poor knowledge to design this is failling me. For example editing the System Name:

Class System added:

```
inline bool ChangeSystemName(std::string newName) { m_Name = newName;}
```

Class SystemArray added:

```
void ChangeSystemName(unsigned int systemID,std::string newName) {
    std::string oldName = GetSystemName(systemID);
    if(m_Systems[systemID].ChangeSystemName(newName))
    {
        std::cout << "Name of system: " << oldName << " changed to: " << GetSystemName(systemID) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to handle this? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Missing headers

I needed to add these includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
```

## Uninitialised members

The default constructor of `System` leaves both `m_Name` and `m_ID` uninitialised, which is dangerous.  Does it make any sense to default-construct a solar system?  I would just remove that constructor.  We'll need to change how we add to maps, of course, so as not to need default-construction.

## Use `std::move()` to construct members

Instead of initialising `mn_Name` by copy-constructing from `name`, note that we don't use `name` afterwards.  So we can initialise using `m_Name{std::move(name)}`, reducing the amount of copying going on.

## Pointless destructors

The empty destructors could be written `= default`, but simpler still is to not write them at all.  The compiler-generated destructors will do the same, but better.

## Unnecessary flushing

We use a `std::endl` in a lot of places where there's no need to flush output buffers.  These can all be replaced by plain newline.

## Unused member

`m_ID` is never used, so we don't need to store it.

## Wrong stream

The tracing output from the constructor looks like it should be sent to the *standard log stream* `std::clog` rather than to standard output.

## Naming

`SystemArray` is a bit misleading, because it doesn't represent an array.  I'd give it a name that shows what it's *for*, such as `Galaxy`.  On a related note, "system" is a highly-overloaded term in software, so I'd rename that to `SolarSystem`.

## Don't return constant objects

There's no need to return a constant string from `GetSystemName()`; there's no reason that callers shouldn't be able to do what they like with their copy.  We could return a *reference* to constant string or a mutable string.  However, we should treat the `System` object as constant in this function.

Also, let the compiler choose which functions to inline - they usually make better choices than humans.

## Simplify creation of `SystemArray`

We can initialise the `std::map` with its first member:

```
private:
    std::string m_Name;
    std::map<unsigned int, SolarSystem> m_Systems;
    unsigned int m_SystemCount = 1;

public:
    SystemArray(std::string name)
        : m_Name{std::move(name)},
          m_Systems{{0, {0, "DEFAULT"}}}
    {
    }
```

## Choose containers wisely

I really can't see why we're using a `std::map` and then populating it sequentially.  That looks much better suited to a `std::vector`.

And we don't need `m_SystemCount`, because that's always the same as the collection's size.

---

## Improved code

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class SolarSystem
{
    std::string m_name;
    unsigned int m_id;

public:
    SolarSystem(unsigned int id, std::string name)
        : m_name{std::move(name)},
          m_id{id}
    {
        std::clog << "Generated SolarSystem\n";
    };

    std::string name() const
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    unsigned id() const
    {
        return m_id;
    }
};

class Galaxy
{
    std::string m_Name;
    std::vector<SolarSystem> m_Systems;

public:
    Galaxy(std::string name)
        : m_Name{std::move(name)},
          m_Systems{{0, "DEFAULT"}}
    {
    }

    void create(std::string name)
    {
        m_Systems.emplace_back(m_Systems.size(), name);
    }

    std::string name(unsigned int systemID) const
    {
        if (systemID >= m_Systems.size()) {
            return "Unable to get name";
        }

        return m_Systems[systemID].name();
    }

    auto begin() const
    {
        return m_Systems.begin();
    }
    auto end() const
    {
        return m_Systems.end();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Galaxy newGalaxy("Milky Way");
    newGalaxy.create("Sol");
    newGalaxy.create("Tol");
    newGalaxy.create("Foo");

    for(auto const& s: newGalaxy) {
        std::cout << s.id() << ": " << s.name() << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

## Adding the rename functionality

Now let's look at how we change a name.  We don't need to involve `Galaxy` in this at all, if it's able to give use a reference to a solar system - we just get that reference and change it ourselves:

```
class SolarSystem
{
    ⋮
public:
    void set_name(std::string name)
    {
        m_name = std::move(name);
    }
};


class Galaxy
{
    ⋮
public:
    auto& operator[](unsigned int id)
    {
        return m_Systems[id];
    }
}
```

---

## Completed code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class SolarSystem
{
    std::string m_name;
    unsigned int m_id;

public:
    SolarSystem(unsigned int id, std::string name)
        : m_name{std::move(name)},
          m_id{id}
    {
        std::clog << "Generated SolarSystem\n";
    };

    std::string name() const
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    unsigned id() const
    {
        return m_id;
    }

    void set_name(std::string name)
    {
        m_name = std::move(name);
    }
};

class Galaxy
{
    std::string m_Name;
    std::vector<SolarSystem> m_Systems;

public:
    Galaxy(std::string name)
        : m_Name{std::move(name)},
          m_Systems{{0, "DEFAULT"}}
    {
    }

    void create(std::string name)
    {
        m_Systems.emplace_back(m_Systems.size(), name);
    }

    auto& operator[](unsigned int id)
    {
        return m_Systems[id];
    }

    std::string name(unsigned int systemID) const
    {
        if (systemID >= m_Systems.size()) {
            return "Unable to get name";
        }

        return m_Systems[systemID].name();
    }

    auto begin() const
    {
        return m_Systems.begin();
    }
    auto end() const
    {
        return m_Systems.end();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Galaxy newGalaxy("Milky Way");
    newGalaxy.create("Sol");
    newGalaxy.create("Tol");
    newGalaxy.create("Foo");

    newGalaxy[0].set_name("Kol");

    for(auto const& s: newGalaxy) {
        std::cout << s.id() << ": " << s.name() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all apologies for the lack of includes and thank you for the in depth explanation for the changes they all actually clicked in my brain and it is a good learning moment, however [std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) I need to be careful when using it, since it actually clear the first variable of it's value correct? Meaning that it can only be used on the last time I need to use the moving variable.

Comment: Yes, but remember that because we've been passed _by value_, it's clear that that particular copy isn't used again after it's moved from.

Comment: For future reference - I believe some of my coding decisions were wrongly made since I was using multiple files and the way they were being include into the solution caused compiler errors that instead of me addressing them compounding the decisions. Example initializing the std::map or the default constr and destr on the SolarSystem Class. I was able to identify those errors when implementing the std::vector as suggested by @TobySpeight I got errors regarding the vector initialization with an object as well as on the function for the [] operator. This was solved by changing the #include order

Comment: If you have improved your code to your satisfaction @Tiago, then you might want to ask a follow-up question with that improved code to see what reviewers think (as you probably know, you mustn't edit the code in _this_ question now it has an answer!).

Comment: thank you for the advice. I think your suggestions make sense and until I finalize the data reading part to populate SolarSystems with Bodies there is no need for a review. Your assessment really helped me improve and learn.